# How to get an array of user roles with or without a specific capability?

Tags: wpdb, user-roles, capabilities

Although it might seem a silly task, I simply can't find a method to get an array of all WordPress **user roles** that don't have a specific capability.

With the function bellow I'm able to get all available user roles, but how can I filter those so I can return only the user roles with or without a specific capability, let's say it's the `upload_files` capability? Would it be doable?

```
function get_roles_that_cant_upload_files() {
    global $wp_roles;

    if ( !isset( $wp_roles ) ) $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    $available_roles = array();

    $available_roles = $wp_roles->get_names();

    return $available_roles;
}
```

I've searched everywhere through WordPress docs and the web for a proper WP core function, which seems not to exist, not even a filter.

I was hoping to get only the user roles without the `upload_files` capability. Doing so, I'd use it to feed a select field within a plugin options and then I'd set another capability for the selected user roles.

I'm not a developer, so I've tried a few "hacks" without success. It seems the user capabilities are stored in `wp_options` table, this makes me think if would it be possible to perform a database query in order to get those results?

Any inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
function get_roles_that_cant($capability) {
    global $wp_roles;

    if ( !isset( $wp_roles ) ) $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    $available_roles_names = $wp_roles->get_names();//we get all roles names

    $available_roles_capable = array();
    foreach ($available_roles_names as $role_key => $role_name) { //we iterate all the names
        $role_object = get_role( $role_key );//we get the Role Object
        $array_of_capabilities = $role_object->capabilities;//we get the array of capabilities for this role
        if(!isset($array_of_capabilities[$capability]) || $array_of_capabilities[$capability] == 0){ //we check if the upload_files capability is present, and if its present check if its 0 (FALSE in Php)
            $available_roles_capable[$role_key] = $role_name; //we populate the array of capable roles
        }
    }
    return $available_roles_capable;
}
```

i took you function and add the logic to get the rol object and get all the capabilities for that object and check if the rol has that capability, also i made it general so you can send which [capability](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities) you want to check, use it like this:

```
get_roles_that_cant('upload_files');
```

it will return an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [contributor] => Contributor
    [subscriber] => Subscriber
)
```

so you can make your dropdown values using the `$key` of the array and the option string using the `$value` of the array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It's a great function by the way! I've been trying to recreate the logic in order to do not return those user rules without a specific capability. If I use the function like `get_roles_that_cant('upload_files');` I still get the user roles that "has" the `upload_files` cap, when in fact I'm looking for those that "has not" the `upload_files` capability. In my plugin options I intend to successfully prevent all user roles that already has the capability from being selected, this way those user roles would remain untouched.

Comment: i see it, i just updated the code, it was pretty late for me i made it the other way around by mistake, try it it should return the ones that dont have the capability now.

Comment: Thanks @David Lee, you're a genius! My plugin is getting awesome thanks to you that helped me to overcome this issue. Have a look at it, I'm so glad t's working, https://cldup.com/b-gBoKnhyv.png

Comment: nice!, that is looking good by the way.